# How to get foreign key value from not fetched relationship?

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

Having two entities defining relationship by `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToMany`, how can I get foreign key without asking from related object and just by looking at defining tables?  How do I get `OWNER_ID` from `Owned` by something like `owned.getOwnerId()` instead of `owned.getOwner().getId()` and still be able to `owned.getOwner()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Map the field in your entity as a basic mapping allows you to use the foreign key directly.  You can keep the object reference mapping as well, but one of the two mappings must then be marked as insertable=false, updatable=false so that JPA knows which mapping controls the field in the event they show different values.